# Get data from 2 tables with a join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have these 2 tables : `keyword` and `keyword_translated`

```
keyword
id
name

keyword_translated
id
translation
keyword_id
```

I want to get all `keyword`, doesn't matter has or not relation with `keyword_translated`. At the end I want to get something like :

```
[
  [
      keyword_id => 1,
      keyword_name => 'firstKeyword'
      keyword_translated_id => 1, // if exist relation between `keyword` and `keyword_translated`
      keyword_translated_translation => 'This is translation of firstKeyword' // if exist relation between `keyword` and `keyword_translated`
  ],
  [
      keyword_id => 2,
      keyword_name => 'secondKeyword'
      keyword_translated_id => null, // if didn't exist relation between `keyword` and `keyword_translated`
      keyword_translated_translation => null // if didn't exist relation between `keyword` and `keyword_translated`
  ],
]
```

I tried like this :

```
$keywords = DB::table('keywords')
        ->join('keywords_translated', 'keywords.id', '=', 'keywords_translated.keyword_id')
        ->select('keywords.*', 'keywords_translated.*')
        ->get();
```

But I have empty data. What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Looks like there's a type on `DB::table('keywords')`. `keywords` -> `keyword`. Also, it sounds like you want to use `leftJoin` instead of `join`.

Comment: Please try to refrain from apologising for your English - you've added that 40 times in your questions, and it doesn't help make questions clearer. Similarly, there is no need to add "thanks" (or abominations like "thx"), for much the same reason - the community prefers succinct and technical writing here.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

use `leftjoin` instead of `join` like this:

```
$keywords = DB::table('keywords')
        ->leftjoin('keywords_translated', 'keywords.id', '=','keywords_translated.keyword_id')
        ->select(
           'keywords.id as keyword_id',
           'keywords.name as keyword_name',
           'keyword_translated.id as keyword_translated_id',
           'keyword_translated.translation as keyword_translated_translation',
        )
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Save this image for future reference.

[image]